# jtextpane html image doesnt load

Tags: java, html, image, jtextpane

I wanted to create a scrollable jtextpane with some html text. Inside, there are some image elements. If I open the file with a browser the image show up correctly and everything is fine.

My problem is that I cant just simply modify the text with some java code because its located inside a properties file, so Im kind of forced to get the right location path.

Does someone know a trick to still use the html text with an properties file with working images?

```
text=<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <h3>Seer:</h3>
     <img src="icons/roles/seer_icon.png" align="left" height="64"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `src="icons/roles/seer_icon.png"` is relative to the document base.  If there were an actual HTML file, the document base would be that file.  If you load the content as a String instead of from a URL, you need to [set the base yourself](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html#setBase(java.net.URL)) so relative URLs will resolve correctly.

Comment: @VGR my folder structure looks like that [link](https://imgur.com/a/AoIYa9f) meaning my html should be edited to that right? `<img src="../../../../../resources/icons/roles/villager_icon.png" align="left" height="64"/>`

Comment: No.  I repeat that the src attribute is relative to the document base.  Adding `../` will not address that, because there is no document base when you load the content from a String.

Comment: @VGR oh okay, now I understand, but as far as I know I cant use setBase() inside of a properties file, so where should I use it inside my gui file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `src="icons/roles/seer_icon.png"` does not start with http: or https:, it is a *relative URL.*  A relative URL’s true location depends on the URL which acts as the base context for the HTML document.

If you load HTML content from a URL using setPage, the base is that URL.  But if you load from a String, as you’re probably doing since you are getting the content from a properties file, there is no base URL.  Which means `src="icons/roles/seer_icon.png"` makes no sense—there is no base to resolve it against.

But you can specify the base yourself:

```
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) textPane.getStyledDocument();
doc.setBase(MyApplication.class.getResource("/"));
```

Note that HTML may not be the best way to show content, unless you need to give the user the ability to copy and paste it.  You can always create the content yourself:

```
// Properties file contains:
// text=Seer:
// icon=/icons/roles/seer_icon.png

String headingText = properties.getProperty("text");
String iconPath = properties.getProperty("icon");

JLabel headingLabel = new JLabel(headingText);
Font font = headingLabel.getFont();
font = font.deriveFont(24f);
headingLabel.setFont(font);

headingLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 12, 0));

Icon icon = new ImageIcon(MyApplication.class.getResource(iconPath));
JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(icon);

JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
content.add(headingLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
content.add(iconLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```